# Using jQuery to make it look like a Responsive form

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

My whole web is responsive but my form is not. I figured the missing item was this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

As I didn't have the "form group" in my codes everything but the form is responsive and it does not look nice on mobile.

Is there a jQuery code to substitute this `<div class="form-group">`or a jQuery that helps me with making my form responsive?

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is responsive, then you should also use CSS media queries for your form. Javascript is not needed at this point.

Comment: yes, you can divide into large, medium and small view. For more details see the `@media` selector.